# Show moderator flags left in /review

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, flags, review

The "flag for removal" button silently consumes your daily suggested moderator flag allowance. You probably don't really mind this, but it would be neat if the remaining flags counter was displayed -- just like it is displayed in all other dialogs you can spend your flags in.

Here's a pretty exciting mockup:

[image: Utterly Stunning Mockup]

Comment: Wot, no freehand circles?

Comment: No drop-shadow either. Badp, *bad* p!

Comment: That's not a moon!

Comment: @Shog9 good work. *Now* it's complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be deployed in the next drop.

But, please keep in mind ...

http://twitter.com/#!/codinghorror/status/1165936105